# Json MultiArray & ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array, servicestack

There is a line {"level": [{"level": 1, "points": 0, "name": "Some"}, {"level": 2, "points": 50, "name": "Second level "}, {" level ": 3," points ": 100," name ":" third level "}]}

How to fix the existing code or to add to get at the request when the exact same line?

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;

namespace MSWA.Classes  
{  
  [DataContract]  
  [Description("Get config")]  
  [RestService("/gconf")]  
  public class GameConfiguration  
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string puid { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class GameConfigurationResponse
  {
    [DataMember]
    public LevelList ll;

    [DataMember]
    public string TestResponse { get; set; }
  }

  // Level List
  [DataContract]
  public class LevelList
  {
    [DataMember]
    public List<Level> level { get; set; }
  }

  // Desc one level
  [DataContract]
  public class Level
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int level { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int points { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
  }

  /// Create your Web Service implementation
  public class GameConfigurationService : IService<GameConfiguration>
  {
    public object Execute(GameConfiguration request)
    {
      // Original data
      string respValue = "";

      respValue = request.puid;

      if (respValue == null || respValue == "0") respValue = "0";

      Level lvl = new Level(){level=1, points=0, name=""};

      LevelList llist = new LevelList();
      llist.level.Add(lvl);

      return new GameConfigurationResponse
      {
          ll = llist
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **there is a line**? It seems you wanna deserialize the JSON string but it's not clear where!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your question. I think you are asking how to update your existing code so that it outputs this object:

```
{
    "level": [
        {"level": 1, "points": 0, "name": "Some"}, 
        {"level": 2, "points": 50, "name": "Second level"}, 
        {"level": 3, "points": 100, "name": "Third level"} 
     ]
 }
```

You should remove these lines:

```cs
Level lvl = new Level(){level=1, points=0, name=""};

LevelList llist = new LevelList();
llist.level.Add(lvl);
```

And replace with these:

```cs
LevelList llist = new LevelList();
llist.level = new List<Level>();
llist.level.Add(new Level { level = 1, points = 0, name = "Some" }); 
llist.level.Add(new Level { level = 2, points = 50, name = "Second level" }); 
llist.level.Add(new Level { level = 3, points = 100, name = "Third level" });
```

---

### Update:

I presume from your comment you want to change `GameConfigurationResponse` to just output the `List<Level>` without having the `LevelList` object?

```
[DataContract]
public class GameConfigurationResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Level> level { get; set; } 
}
```

So the corresponding `Execute` method would be:

```
public object Execute(GameConfiguration request)
{
    // Original data
    string respValue = request.puid ?? "0";

    return new GameConfigurationResponse
    {
        level = new List<Level> {
            new Level { level = 1, points = 0, name = "Some" },
            new Level { level = 2, points = 50, name = "Second level" }, 
            new Level { level = 3, points = 100, name = "Third level" }
        }
    };
}
```

I am not sure what you are using `respValue` for. I have simplified it to `string respValue = request.puid ?? "O";` That will set respValue to `request.puid` unless it is `null`, in which case it will be set to 0. But you aren't using this value, at least not in the code posted.

Comment: [DataContract]
        public class GameConfigurationResponse
        {
            [DataMember]
            public List<Level> level { get; set; }
        } and wo LevelList

Comment: @АлексСандерс Did you get this working? Did this help? Please provide feedback. Thanks